# HTC One volume too low

Tags: htc-one, volume-control

My `HTC One` is kind of old (2.5 years) and the volume is progressively deteriorating.  I can barely hear the other side when the volume is on highest.  Is there any way to adjust the volume beside the volume button, which is already maxed?

Answer (score -1):

Try to carefully clean the speaker with a toothpick